# Decoupling between service and controller e.g. not using $http

Tags: angularjs

I'm quite new to `AngularJS` and I'm trying to find a nice way to do implement the Controller-Service communication for a simple `REST` client I'm currently writing.

On the web I find a lot of examples where a `controller` delegates `$http` requests to a `service` but then still rely on the `$http` object to perform the success/error handling. This is IMHO not thoroughly decoupled, as the `$http` object is "leaked" to the `controller` layer. The `controller` should be ignorant of *how* the data is retrieved -- it should just ask the service layer "give me/do this/etc."

I have a `java` background where you typically decouple controller-service by using POJO's but sometimes this can be an anti-pattern too I've heard.

What would be best practice?

Comment: Typically controllers use a `promise` object returned from `$http` request, not the `$http` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just returning promises from my `services`. Here's an example:

Controller:

```
$scope.removeTask = function(task) {
    BoardService.removeTask({task_id: task.id}).then(function() {
           // Task was removed
    });
}
```

Service:

```
this.removeTask = function(data) {
    return $http.post($rootScope.serverRoot + '/task/delete', data);            
}
```

Doing it this way does not require you to inject `$http` in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally fine to use `$http` service in a controller and react on its returning promise. However, if you have logic that is used somewhere else too, you start putting it in a new service which you would then inject instead of the `$http` service.

But again, this would just bubble up another promise one which you would react on using the resolve or reject callback.

Also talking about RESTful interfaces, you might wanna take a look at angulars `$resource` service, which is an additional layer on top of `$http` that gives you a RESTFul api for RESTFul APIs on the web. There you would create resource instances and ask them to get data for your, which is probably exactly what you want.

Comment: But if you react on the http promise you are somehow coupled to the way $http is returning data...

Comment: Well yes, you always have to react on what comes back from a service you use. There's no other way.